# Power Bi - Modelling

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, data-modeling

I'm feeling quite frustrated as I try to resolve an issue. I currently have 19 tables (listed below), and I've been grappling with finding the most efficient model setup to ensure that my queries run effectively in Power Bi which is a new tool for me.

Quite a big ask. I dont want to put everything on here for obvious privacy reasons but also my data dictionery is quite large.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

-

1. **Beneficiaries Table:**

   - Columns:

     - What is your current situation
     - Post code
     - Details of Medical Condition
     - School Name
     - Session Title
     - Organisation
     - Interested session
     - Date of Birth (dob)
     - ID
     - Address
     - Avatar
     - Email address
     - Mobile phone
     - Other telephone number
     - Website
     - EDI Values
     - Job Title
     - Membership in any Networks/Forums
     - Comments or Questions
     - Message
     - Relationship to young person
     - Upload your CV
     - Signed
     - Emergency Contact Name
     - Emergency Contact Relationship
     - Emergency Contact Number
     - Emergency Contact Email
     - UpShot ID
     - UpShot ID (text)
     - Team Name
     - Preferred Time
     - Charity ID
     - Created At
     - Created By
     - Email
     - Name
     - Updated At
2. **Beneficiaries Categories Table:**

   - Columns:

     - Charity ID
     - Created At
     - ID
     - Is Default
     - Is Stopped
     - Name
     - Updated At
3. **Beneficiaries Types Categories Table:**

   - Columns:

     - Beneficiary Cat ID
     - Beneficiary Type ID
     - Created At
     - ID
     - Updated At
4. **Changes Table:**

   - Columns:

     - Activity
     - Created At
     - Icon
     - ID
     - Name
     - Participation
     - Stage ID
     - Updated At
5. **Indicators Table:**

   - Columns:

     - Created At
     - ID
     - Indicator Type
     - Instruction
     - Name
     - Approved
     - Ratio Set ID
     - Stage ID
     - Default Question
     - Description
     - Detail
     - Icon
     - Private
     - Unit
     - Updated At
6. **Outcome Indicators Table:**

   - Columns:

     - ID
     - Indicator ID
     - Outcome ID
     - Updated At
7. **Outcomes Table:**

   - Columns:

     - Icon
     - ID
     - Title
     - Updated At
8. **Project Beneficiaries Table:**

   - Columns:

     - Beneficiary ID
     - Created At
     - ID
     - Project ID
     - Updated At
9. **Project Story Categories Table:**

   - Columns:

     - Allow Sign Out Story
     - Created At
     - Display Intro Msg
     - Display Respondent Name
     - ID
     - Is Stopped
     - Project ID
     - Story Category ID
     - Updated At
10. **Projects Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Beneficiary Category ID
      - Charity ID
      - Created At
      - ID
      - Name
      - Updated At
11. **Ratio Sets Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Created At
      - ID
      - Ratio Category ID
      - Title
      - Updated At
12. **Stories Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Beneficiary IDs
      - Location
      - Number
      - Project ID
      - Story Category ID
      - Story Group
      - Actual Created At
      - Approved
      - Charity ID
      - Created At
      - Edited By
      - ID
      - Text
      - Updated At
      - User ID
13. **Story Beneficiaries Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Beneficiary ID
      - Created At
      - ID
      - Project ID
      - Story ID
      - Updated At
14. **Story Categories Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Color
      - Created At
      - Current Fields
      - Description
      - ID
      - Intro Msg
      - Is Default
      - Is Stopped
      - Name
      - Scale Indicator Choices
      - Story Privacy Data
      - Updated At
15. **Story Changes Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Change ID
      - Created At
      - ID
      - Known Beneficiaries Count
      - Number
      - Story ID
      - Unknown Beneficiaries Count
      - Updated At
16. **Story Indicator Beneficiaries Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Beneficiary ID
      - Created At
      - ID
      - Indicator ID
      - Indicator Type
      - Number
      - Outcome ID
      - Story ID
      - Sub Ratio ID
      - Updated At
17. **Story Indicators Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Created At
      - ID
      - Indicator ID
      - Indicator Question ID
      - Known Beneficiaries Count
      - Number
      - Outcome ID
      - Story ID
      - Unknown Beneficiaries Count
      - Updated At
18. **Story Change Beneficiaries Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Beneficiary ID
      - Change ID
      - Created At
      - ID
      - Story ID
      - Updated At
19. **Sub Ratios Table:**

    - Columns:

      - Created At
      - Default Criteria
      - Default Points
      - ID
      - Name
      - Priority
      - Ratio Set ID
      - Updated At

Tried many variations to model the data none of which is proving right

Comment: Try Power BI GPT | Power BI EXpert in gptstore/ open.ai https://gptstore.ai/gpts/UySIsrCfc9-power-bi-gpt

Comment: I'd suggest breaking down the problem by focusing on specific queries that you want to be able to perform, otherwise it's going to be difficult to gauge how well the data model is suited for your problem. At first glance it looks reasonable.